# how to use installed oracle 11g in ubuntu?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

I am using Ubuntu operating system. But I am a user of Windows 7 or Windows xp so I am not understanding to how to use after installed Oracle 11g database.

I have install this database on machine but I don't known how to use it like -

1. How to start it? .
2. How to create database on it? .
3. How to create table on it? .
4. How to operate it? .

I can see icon namely- Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on my Ubuntu desktop.whenever I click on this icon then one link is being opened on browser- 
`http://localhost:9090/apex/f?p=4950`

but no details is being displayed on this link.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 5 minute guide to Oracle. You need at least 2 days.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm